# SQL SELECT last entry based on several conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

In my case, I would like to select the last record for each couple (company_id, product_id) and return only those for which stock is not 0.

```
company_id  product_id    stock        date
    165         6           0       2017-01-09
    168         4         900000    2017-01-08
    165         6          1520     2017-01-07
    165         5        1200000    2017-01-06
    167         2           0       2017-01-05
    167         1        1401700    2017-01-04
    167         1        1450800    2017-01-03
    168         4           0       2017-01-02
    167         2        2360400    2017-01-01
```

In this example, the table would be:

```
company_id  product_id    stock        date
    168         4         900000    2017-01-08
    165         5        1200000    2017-01-06
    167         1        1401700    2017-01-04
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a subquery to get the max date per company/product.
- Then join back to source table and filter out zero stock rows.

Query

```
select  t1.company_id, t1.product_id, t1.stock, t1.date
from    tablename t1
        inner join (
            select  company_id, product_id, max(date) maxdate
            from    tablename
            group by company_id, product_id) t2
        on  t1.company_id = t2.company_id
        and t1.product_id = t2.product_id
        and t1.date = t2.maxdate
where t1.stock <> 0
```

Comment: If the max-date for a company_id/product_id has a zero stock, no rows at all will be returned for that company_id/product_id. Is that what OP wants?

Comment: @jarlh That's for OP to decide. But it matches the sample input/output. Of course if rows aren't keyed by `company, product, date` there will be other problems.

Comment: @jarlh I do not want to return the couple company_id/product_id in case the last row in date is a zero-stock. Sorry if my question was not as clear as I wanted.. Thanks for helping me anyway !

Answer (score 3):

Have a sub-query that returns each company_id/product_id with its last date (where stock is non-zero.) `JOIN` with that result:

```
select t1.company_id, t1.product_id, t1.stock, t1.date
from tablename t1
join (select company_id, product_id, max(date) maxdate
      from tablename
      where stock <> 0 group by company_id, product_id) t2
  on  t1.company_id = t2.company_id
  and t1.product_id = t2.product_id
  and t1.date = t2.maxdate
where stock <> 0
```

Comment: Looks like OP needs `where stock <> 0` in the outer `select` (see `company_id  product_id= 165 product_id= 6` rows)

Comment: @serg, I guess that can be useful too. No such sample data, so I didn't care... I'll add in anyway!

Comment: @Serg That row doesn't match on `and t1.date = t2.maxdate`

Comment: @CraigYoung Oops, wrong copy-paste, it should be `company_id = 165 product_id= 6` rows.

Comment: @Serg Yeah I figured that. But point is the sub-query returns: `company_id = 165, product_id= 6, maxdate = 2017-01-07`. So the outer query doesn't need to additionally filter `where stock <> 0` because the row with `stock = 0, date = 2017-01-09` is already excluded.

Comment: If only one row per company_id, product_id, date is allowed, the outer WHERE is not needed. If several rows are allowed for the same date, it can be used to avoid zero-stock rows in the result.

Comment: @CraigYoung 2017-01-07, exactly. So the query will return a row for this key. But OP's example says it shouldn't . Subquery must return `maxdate=2017-01-09` and then outer select must filter it out due to `stock = 0`.

Comment: If there are several rows for the same date, you should probably aggregate stock on that date: `select company_id, product_id, sum(stock), date from ... group by company_id, product_id, date`

Comment: @Serg Ah ok, I get your point. But then simply adding outer `where stock <> 0` doesn't solve the problem. ... Need to also delete the inner `where stock <> 0`.